# Making C# code generate webform with Events

Tags: c#

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        if (Request.QueryString.Count > 0)
        {

            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter("select * from personalization where ponumber = '" + Request.QueryString["PO"] + "'", VisualConnect);
            adapter.Fill(dt);

            if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
            {
                for (Int32 i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count; i++)
                {
                    HtmlGenericControl tr = new HtmlGenericControl("tr");
                    HtmlGenericControl td = new HtmlGenericControl("td");
                    HtmlGenericControl td1 = new HtmlGenericControl("td");

                    Label lbcustomename = new Label();
                    lbcustomename.ID = "lbline1";
                    lbcustomename.Text = "Recipient Name:  ";
                    td.Controls.Add(lbcustomename);
                    tr.Controls.Add(td);

                    TextBox txtcustombox = new TextBox();
                    txtcustombox.ID = "txtline1";
                    txtcustombox.Text = dt.Rows[i]["line1"].ToString();
                    td1.Controls.Add(txtcustombox);
                    tr.Controls.Add(td1);
                    placeholder.Controls.Add(tr);

                    //Add button  after last record  
                    if (i == dt.Rows.Count - 1)
                    {
                        tr = new HtmlGenericControl("tr");
                        td = new HtmlGenericControl("td");
                        Button btnSubmit = new Button();
                        btnSubmit.ID = "btnSubmit";
                        btnSubmit.Click += btnSubmit_Click;
                        btnSubmit.Text = "Submit";
                        btnSubmit.Attributes.Add("runat", "server");
                        td.Controls.Add(btnSubmit);
                        td.Attributes.Add("Colspan", "2");
                        td.Attributes.Add("style", "text-align:center;");
                        tr.Controls.Add(td);
                        placeholder.Controls.Add(tr);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private void btnSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // do something
    }
}
```

I have added this code to dynamically draw up fields from a database for input where the user would click the Submit button when completed. However, whenever I click the submit button, it wants to reload the page and the btnSubmit_Click event is never invoked instead. Am I missing something?

Comment: *"whenever I click the submit button, it wants to reload the page"* - This is expected behavior for Web Forms controls.  The entire page reloads, the `Page_Load` event is invoked, and then the button's click event (server-side) is invoked.  Are you looking to use AJAX to make a request to the server without reloading the page?  If so then a standard Web Forms button doesn't do that.

Comment: This: `btnSubmit.Attributes.Add("runat", "server");` isn't going to do anything but emit the attribute to the client. *It's already running at the server*. That's what this code is. That attribute triggers generation of the kind of code you have here when the .aspx/.ascx file is being parsed. It doesn't mean anything outside of the .aspx/.ascx file.